# UPDATE data in the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I want to show the selected ID data in the form and EDIT it and UPDATE in the database. I selected the data from the database and put it in the input tag but it doesn't work. Please help!

```
<html>
<body>
<?
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","");
mysql_select_db("db_ncs",$db);
$id = $_GET['s_id'];
if($id)
{
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE s_id=$id");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
?>

<form method="post" action="update.php">
    Name:<input type="Text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['s_name'];?>" /><br>
    Contact:<input type="Text" name="contact" value="<?php echo $row['s_contact'];?>" /><br>
    Address:<input type="Text" name="address" value="<?php echo $row['s_address'];?>" /><br>
    E-mail:<input type="Text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['s_email'];?>" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
</form>

<?
if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
    $name = $_POST['s_name'];
    $contact = $_POST['s_contact'];
    $address = $_POST['s_address'];
    $email = $_POST['s_email'];
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_student
            SET (s_name='$name', s_contact='$contact', s_address='$address', s_email='$email')
            WHERE s_id=$id";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);       
    if($res)
        {
            echo "Upadate Successfull!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Sorry!";
        }
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your SQL query is not valid. You have to add quotes around string values.

Comment: This code is susceptible to sql injection - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to pass the id.

Add this between the `<form>` tags.

```
<input type="hidden" name="s_id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
```

You also need to make your methods consistent. The form submits the data via `method="get"` but you ask for it via `$_POST`. You also need to make the input names consistent with the names you ask for, by either adding or removing the "s_" in the appropriate places.

Comment: but why type=hidden and name=s_id

Comment: @mani Because you don't want the user to change the data of an item he hasn't viewed, so he shouldn't change it while editing. `name=s_id` because that's what you called it in the `$_GET` statement. It doesn't need to be any specific value, the just have to match.

Answer (score 0):

In the form you have `method="get"` but you use `$_POST` in your PHP code. Try to define your form as below:

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
```

---

Your SQL query should be (added quotes):

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_student
        SET (s_name='$name', s_contact='$contact', s_address='$address', s_email='$email')
        WHERE s_id=$id";
```

Try adding this after `mysql_query`:

```
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Do not use `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained: use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) of [MySQLi](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but i have to point you to some omissions in your code:

- if `$_POST['update']` is set, that doesn't mean the other variables are also set. They can be empty if user didn't enter anything in a field. You should check if every `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables are set by using [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).
- your code is so insecure! You should escape every variable before using it in a query. Use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for that. I also suggest you to use [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) along with escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't he have to use the `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` to get the results?

```
// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

// Use result
// Attempting to print $result won't allow access to information in the resource
// One of the mysql result functions must be used
// See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(), mysql_fetch_row(), etc.
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['address'];
    echo $row['age'];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

above is just an example.

---

update:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE s_id=$id");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); //  I think you have to add this line here, don't you?
?>



<form method="post" action="update.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="s_id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />
    Name:<input type="Text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['s_name'];?>" /><br>
    Contact:<input type="Text" name="contact" value="<?php echo $row['s_contact'];?>" /><br>
    Address:<input type="Text" name="address" value="<?php echo $row['s_address'];?>" /><br>
    E-mail:<input type="Text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['s_email'];?>" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
</form>
```

---

update 2:

when you are going to update, the method up there `$id = $_GET['s_id'];` is still looking for a param called 's_id' will come via HTTP GET, but it doesn't!

a quick workaround may be this,
`<form method="post" action="update.php?<?php echo $id;?>">`

and don't forget to add,

`$id= $_POST['s_id'];` after `$email = $_POST['s_email'];`!

---

update 3:

Hmm, You still need this `<input type="hidden" name="s_id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" />` and don't forget to add,

`$id= $_POST['s_id'];` after `$email = $_POST['s_email'];`!

Comment: `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`  I think you have to add this line, don't you?

Comment: and notice the `$result=mysql_query()` , assignment of the resultSet to var `$result`

Comment: sorry i again cant get you... i m really weak in php

Comment: I get this error while updating...... Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\wamp\www\ncs\update.php on line 8

Comment: Hmm, what's on line 8? mysql_fetch_array()?

Comment: I have edited the post... everything is fine but when i press UPDATE it gives me SORRY...

Answer (score 0):

Your form has fields like `name="contact"`, but when you try to get the values you use `$_POST['s_contact']`. These need to match.

The reason you need the hidden s_id field in the form is so that you will update the same row that was edited.  Your UPDATE statement contains `WHERE s_id=$id`, so you need to get the original id this way. It's hidden because you don't want the user to be able to change the ID when editing.